# I have a adj matrix graph and i was wondering how do i traverse from a specific vertex to another specific vertex

Tags: c

Traverse from 1 vertex to another using BFS.

```
#define N 9635

int ChainOfWords(int Id1, int Id2, int used[N], int depth)
{
    depth = depth + 1;
    used[Id1] = depth;
    for(int i = 1; i<n; i++){
        if(!used[i] && i!=Id2){
            ChainOfWords(i, Id2, used, depth);
        }   
        else{
            return 1
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int used[N]` is not a c# syntax. You need to mention what is BFS. And what is data structure. And why your code doesn't work. Also please don't post homework questions as is, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: An adjacent graph is a square matrix.  A square matrix has 8 neighbor cells (except around the outside of the matrix where the corners have 3 neighbors and the edges have 5 neighbors).  The neighbors vertex are the non zero cells in the matrix.  So you need to go to transverse the matrix by testing all neighbor cells and transverse the ones that are not zero.  So if you are at cell (2,2)  you have to transverse cells (1,1), (1,2),(1,3), (2,1), (2,3), (3,1), (3,2), and (3,3) if they do not contain zero.

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally, an adjacency matrix is a represents a graph by indexing the matrix by two node ids:

```
int Graph[N][N];
...
int Edge(int from, int to) {
     return Graph[from][to];
}
```

A non-zero return value from Edge(1, 2) would indicate that there is an *Edge* between *vertices* 1 and 2; a zero would indicate no such *Edge* exists.
Adjacency matrices can quickly answer questions like: which nodes is *k* connected to:

```
PrintConnection(int k) {
   int i;
   printf("%d:", k);
   for (i=0; i < N; i++) {
       if (Graph[k][i]) {
           printf(" %d", i);
       }
   }
   printf("\n");
}
```

and you can perform transformations upon the adjacency matrix to tease out further information.   A useful one is the transitive closure, whereby you find the cases where *Edge(a, c) == 0 && Edge(a, b) != 0 && Edge(b, c) != 0*; then set Graph[a][c] = 1. for every case in the graph.    Once annotated, the function Edge(a,b) answers *is there a path from a to b, perhaps going through other vertices, in the graph".  There is an efficient dynamic algorithm to produce this by Warshall.

I hope this helps....